# VB.net project with SQL Server Management Studio DB and Crystal Reports to .exe setup file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I completed my project (PoS) using VB.NET 2019 community. Now I want to make its setup (.exe).

The Project i.e my PoS system is depend on SQL Server Database. (which created by SQL Server Management Studio and the DB is not attached with the project files, rather it is just connected by the connection string)

I have also Crystal Reports in my Project.

How I can make my project exe file with the database, and to install all the configuration on any PC.
What I shall do according to the connection string ; since the server name will change?
I don't have background in that ;

thanks in anticipation

I tried a lot but all in vain.

Comment: Are you asking about how to deploy the DB? Or how to connect to an existing DB already deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: make the connection string a configuration setting.

Option 2: use an ODBC connection. That would allow the ODBC DSN on each machine to map to the actual server.